# How to properly handle logout request after session expires when using WSFederationAuthenticationModule?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, session-timeout, adfs, ws-federation

I am using WSFederationAuthenticationModule for authentication. When the user is not authenticated it redirects them to ADFS web agent accordingly. The ADFS cookie lasts longer than the app session, so sometimes they will just be looped right back into the application.

Pretty much every time this is what I want, the user tries to do something, it redirects them if the session is expired and they come back around (either after logging in again or after it finds the cookie to still be good) and then they can do what they want. However, **if they are clicking 'logout' I want them to be logged out**. But the Module is intercepting and sending them back around and then they have to click 'logout' again once the session is restored.

Logout is an MVC api controller action. I am not sure if I want to take it out from behind the security because it also triggers some clean-up things for the app (I realize this is also a problem because potentially if they never click logout those things won't happen but that is a different issue).

I feel like I must be missing something with WSFederationAuthenticationModule and ADFS... something just doesn't feel right about making the logout action an anonymous/public action. There must be some consideration for this in the intentions of WSFederationAuthenticationModule but I can't seem to pin it down.

Comment: How is your web.config with module ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand Your authentication is kept via an Auth cookie. You should try adding the following in your app controller under your logout action:

```
     FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.SignOut();
     return View("LogOut");
```

This will log them out. Now if the "LogOut" view cannot be accessed by an unauthenticated person it will redirect back to your login page for login.
One more thing, if what you mean above is that after the session expiration when someone tries to access the logout page (although their session is anyhow expired already) they are first redirected to the login module to authenticate (since they need to be authenticated for access to the logout page), huh you could do something like this:

```
     if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
         ...u'r logout logic goes here together with other clean-up...
     else
         ...u could choose to return a view which says he is already logged out
```

or on the login service side (if you control it) check where is the request coming from and take action accordingly.

Comment: Ah I see something now, if the person is unathenticated they are taken to the login page but it is ADFS and has a cookie that could still be good (and is independent of our app), in which case the redirect would happen in a flash and they would be sent back.

Comment: If the person has a cookie that is still good he/she is not taken back to the login page (since a good authcookie gives him access to your logout action) -> logout action is executed. If the cookie is expired and your logout action requires authenticated users then it will go for the redirect to ADFS. It all depends on how u control the access to your logout action. You could leave your logout action public and do the checks inside it as showed above for more control.